# wrapAround not working when set to true

Tags: jquery, html, lightbox2

I'm creating a site that uses lightbox2. The problem I'm having is that I'm trying to get the lightbox to be able to go from the last image to the first image. When I read the documentation it said that I should make wrapAround true. So that is what I did but it isn't working. I haven't gotten any errors in my consol

My main.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    lightbox.option({
      'resizeDuration': 200,
      'wrapAround': true
    });
});
```

My html

```
<div class="col-lg-12 gallery_area">
    <h1>Cutting & styling</h1>

    <div>
        <a href="img/hair_cut/hair_cut.jpg" data-lightbox="hait_cut" data-title="Click the right half of the image to move forward."><img src="img/hair_cut/hair_cut.jpg"></a>
        <a href="img/hair_cut/hair_cut2.jpg" data-lightbox="hait_cut"><img src="img/hair_cut/hair_cut2.jpg"></a>
        <a href="img/hair_cut/hair_style.jpg" data-lightbox="hait_cut"><img src="img/hair_cut/hair_style.jpg"></a>
        <a href="img/hair_cut/hair_style1.jpg" data-lightbox="hait_cut"><img src="img/hair_cut/hair_style1.jpg"></a>
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a working code snippet using codesnippet `<>` button in the editor or at http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Your code looks correct. I did a quick test locally with the same options and the wrapAround option worked correctly. 